# Type of Discontinuity of Multivariable Function

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I'm attempting to identify the type of discontinuity at $(x,t)=(0,0)$ for

$$u(x,t)=\frac{x}{t^{3/2}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{4t}}$$

My gut tells me it's a removable discontinuity, but I don't see anything immediately obvious because the fractions are like $0\times\infty$. I know in $1$-dimension the type of discontinuity can be identified by taking limits around the discontinuity, but I'm unsure how to proceed with this type of analysis in multiple dimensions.

For context, $u(x,t)$ is a solution of the Diffusion IBVP:

\begin{cases}
u_t=u_{xx},  & \text{for $0<x<\infty$, $t>0$} \\
u(0,t)=0, & \text{for $t>0$} \\
u(x,0)=0, &  \text{for $x\ge0$}
\end{cases}

Comment: Well, when you take $t$ to be a small positive real number, it does seem kinda bad ... https://www.desmos.com/calculator/5u5bbvjvuo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: What happens when $t = x^2$?

Comment: Don't worry about it, just show that it doesn't exist.